# Array_multisort does not sort by the second array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array and I would like to sort it so that both arrays are sorted by the flag `SORT_NATURAL` and then either `SORT_ASC` or `SORT_DESC`

So from what I understand it should look like this:

```
array_multisort($array1, SORT_NATURAL, SORT_ASC, $array2, SORT_NATURAL, SORT_ASC, $array);
```

But it seems to only be applying the `SORT_NATURAL` to the `$array1` and the `$array2` is not sorted at all, not even the sort direction is applied.

But as soon as I remove the `SORT_NATURAL` form `$array2`, the sort direction works.

So- `$array1` sorts perfectly fine, but `$array2` does not sort at all.

What could be the problem? Am I missing something?

```
public function sortMultiDimensional(&$array, $subKey, $subKey2, $sortorder_packing_bool=false, $sortorder_packing_secondary_bool=false) {
    $array1 = array();
    $array2 = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $row) {
        $array1[$key]  = $row[$subKey];
        $array2[$key] = $row[$subKey2];
    }
    if($sortorder_packing_bool)
        $sortorder_packing_bool = SORT_ASC;
    else
        $sortorder_packing_bool = SORT_DESC;

    if($sortorder_packing_secondary_bool)
        $sortorder_packing_secondary_bool = SORT_ASC;
    else
        $sortorder_packing_secondary_bool = SORT_DESC;

    array_multisort($array1, $sortorder_packing_bool, SORT_NATURAL, $array2, $sortorder_packing_secondary_bool, SORT_NATURAL, $array);
}
```

Comment: What language is it? PHP?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, yes, this is PHP.

Comment: can you show us two arrays means how you are using those two arrays for sorting ?

Comment: Added the full function

Comment: may I see your array?

Answer (score 0):

Check this example,

```
$data = [];
$data[] = array('volume' => 67, 'edition' => 2);
$data[] = array('volume' => 86, 'edition' => 1);
$data[] = array('volume' => 85, 'edition' => 6);
$data[] = array('volume' => 98, 'edition' => 2);
$data[] = array('volume' => 86, 'edition' => 6);
$data[] = array('volume' => 67, 'edition' => 7);

foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $volume[$key]  = $row['volume'];
    $edition[$key] = $row['edition'];
}

array_multisort($volume, SORT_DESC,SORT_NATURAL, $edition, SORT_ASC,SORT_NATURAL, $data);


print_r($data);
```

Check here working [code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e6b3ea43b0ec1886b76b9f50fcacc75376a1ff50).

It is like group by a,b.

`SORT_NATURAL` working like [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) for example.

Comment: Thanks, that example code made me understand that my code should be working. I added the full function i'm using, maybe you can spot if something is not right after all.

Comment: why sort natural if the numbers are already cast as integers?